# Backbone.js template files in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I've got a Backbone.js with Rails 3.2.3 project and it's working but I want to clean it up and put the template into a separate JST file.

I first created a directory to hold my templates

```
<project>/app/assets/templates/appointments
```

Then I created a file in there called 'show.jst'.

From what I've read I don't need to install Jammit under Rails 3.2.x so I went along and tried to convert the following code to use an external template file:

```
window.AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<h3><%= topic %></h3>'),

    render: function(){
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
window.AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        var html = JST['appointments/show'](attributes);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Inside my show.jst file I've got the following:

```
<h3><%= topic %></h3>
```

(topic is a field within my 'Appointment' model)

This doesn't show any error on the screen, nor does it print anything on the screen.

How do I fix this up so I can use external template files?

**Update**

I've made sure I have required_tree ./templates or ../templates (depending on the location I'm testing out) before all the other require statements like so:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require backbone-rails
#= require_tree ../templates
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./collections
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers
```

I've tried putting my show.jst template file in following

app/assets/javascripts/templates/appointments/show.jst

app/assets/templates/appointments/show.jst

I've tried naming the file show.jst.ejs and including the gem 'ejs' in my Gemfile.

None of these loaded the template. When storing my templates under app/assets I made sure it was in my path with the following:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{ Rails.root }/app/assets/templates"
```

This didn't help either but it did get rid of a Sprockets error.

I still haven't been able to load a template jst file and everything I read suggests a different way. I've tried many of these, maybe their not compatible with Rails 3.2.3 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this works well. In my appointment_show.js I call my template like so:

```
window.AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST["appointments/show"],

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

I make sure that I include the templates directory in my application.js:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require backbone-rails
#= require_tree ../templates
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./collections
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./routers
```

Include these gems in your Gemfile

```
gem 'backbone-rails'
gem 'ejs'
```

Add the app/assets/templates directory to your path within environment.rb:

```
AppointmentsBackboneJs::Application.configure do  
  config.assets.paths << "#{ Rails.root }/app/assets/templates"
end
```

Don't forget to run bundle & restart server